# Use of Subcode matches and data info in a javascript selector engine

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

Hi i am  using ['Qwery" selector engine by dustin diaz](https://github.com/ded/qwery) if you clicked that link, the sample page shows selectors like

`div#baz.thunk a[-data-info*="hello world"] span + strong {}`

and

`#foo a[lang|=en] {} subcodes`

i couldn't understand the use of **subcodes** and **data-info** i even read the CSS2 selector w3c page but could not comprehend from it. Could someone explain using simple example how these works. My notion of **-data-info**  is match innerHTML, Dom properties of a object like below

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Hello</a>
```

and when i executed the below selector it would give me the above element.

```
qwery("a[-data-innerHTML='Hello']");
```

please do clarify my notions and suggest me query to write to get the innerHTML/other properties using qwery selector engine

Comment: I think "subcodes" are a fancy name for attribute values prefixed with something, that can be selected using the `[attr|=val]` attribute selector. You can read about data attributes [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) but I haven't seen the need to prefix `data` with a dash when selecting data attributes.

Comment: @anyone man someone is going on a DownVote spree. If anyone downVotes please do mind to explain why and what could be done to improve the question.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.  Rather than ask someone to educate you on how a selector engine works, can you be more specific with an example of a problem you are trying to solve?  Include some HTML and a question on what object in that HTML you're trying to target with the selector engine.

Comment: @jfriend00 there is html in my question, there is explanation on what i am trying to do, and i don't know how those selectors work. Go downvote i don't mind.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, so I posted to ask for clarification.  If you don't intend to offer any clarification, then I can't help any further.  A selector matches an HTML object, right?  Your have HTML of one link tag.  Is that what you're trying to match?  That wasn't clear to me.  If so, I'd suggest putting a CSS id on the object and matching that.  That's way, easier to match.  It also looks to me like you have backquote characters around Hello in the select rather than regular single quote characters.

Comment: @Deep for what it's worth, I find your question pretty clear - See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good Article

http://www.programmervn.com/2010/11/30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize-part.html

http://www.programmervn.com/2010/11/30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize-part_17.html

Extract:

> Here’s a special one that’ll impress
>   your friends. Not too many people know
>   about this trick. The tilda (~) symbol
>   allows us to target an attribute which
>   has a spaced-separated list of values.
>
> Going along with our custom attribute
>   from number fifteen, above, we could
>   create a data-info attribute, which
>   can receive a space-separated list of
>   anything we need to make note of. In
>   this case, we’ll make note of external
>   links and links to images — just for
>   the example.

```
<a href="http://x.y.com/path/to/image.jpg" 
data-info="external image">Link to image on another server</a>
```

> With that markup in place, now we can target any tags that have either of those values, by using the ~ attributes selector trick.

```
/* Target data-info attr that contains the value "external" */
a[data-info~="external"] {
   color: red;
}

/* And which contain the value "image" */
a[data-info~="image"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```